# Is there a shorthand way to convert a Tuple to a ValueTuple?

Tags: .net, tuples, c#-7.0, valuetuple

I have just included a DLL file into my project and am using a method which returns a `List<Tuple>`. I have only recently became aware of the `ValueTuple` datatype in C# 7 and want to use it instead of the normal Tuples which are returned. I am aware that I could loop through and do the conversion manually however I would like to avoid doing this if possible and was wondering if anyone was aware of a shorthand way to casting a Tuple to a ValueTuple? If I am being ignorant and this isn't possible then I would be grateful if someone could make me aware of the most performant way I could achieve this conversion.

I have looked for a `.ToValueTuple()` method and using a basic cast on the function returning the List with no joy.

When attempting:

```
List<(string entityName, int min, int average, int max)> tupTest = trs.GetEntityStats();
```

I receive the error:

> Cannot convert source type 'System.Collections.Generic.List>' to target type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<(string entityName, int min, int average, int max)>'

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [TupleExtensions Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.tupleextensions) has `ToTuple` and `ToValueTuple` methods.